# Branches coverage in Mockk Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I am using **mockk** library in Kotlin. I am covering branch coverage. I am new to testing. Can someone tell me how to cover all branches? In the given below example, it has two objects one is id as **string** and the name which is hidden is **list**. Thanks

[image]

Can someone explain what are the **12 branches** are for this?

Comment: I should be missing something. I can only count 9.

Comment: @JoãoDias at least can you tell me 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only count 9, but I might be missing something:

| !id.isNullOrEmpty() | Reason | !xxx.isNullOrEmpty() | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | id is not null and not empty | TRUE | xxx is not null and not empty |
| TRUE | id is not null and not empty | FALSE | xxx is empty |
| TRUE | id is not null and not empty | FALSE | xxx is null |
| FALSE | id is null | TRUE | xxx is not null and not empty |
| FALSE | id is empty | TRUE | xxx is not null and not empty |
| FALSE | id is null | FALSE | xxx is null |
| FALSE | id is null | FALSE | xxx is empty |
| FALSE | id is empty | FALSE | xxx is null |
| FALSE | id is empty | FALSE | xxx is empty |